# User gets logged off back to login menu

Tags: 12.04, display, gmail, javascript

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed via alternate installer amd64 fresh with LibreOffice and ncomputing vSpace software installed. I am facing a unique issue here which is little tricky to describe. Whenever I check gmail from firefox/chrome, the user gets logged off the moment I move mouse pointer towards Inbox/Sent/Draft folder on left side. If I keep checking emails it doesn't log off. But the moment pointer is moved towards left side of screen, it just kicks out. Same issue on same machine with Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop version amd64.

syslog/xserver.errors files are not showing anything which can lead to why this is happening. Checked with Unity/Unity2D same issue. YahooMail/Outlook.com work fine without any issues.

Display drivers are showing unknown as of now. `Matrox G200e onboard` is showing in `lspci -vv | grep VGA`.

**Server config:**
Intel Server board 1200s3VPS
Xeon CPU
16GB RAM
120GBx2 SSD Kingston.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

New information: This doesn't happen in Opera. Plus if I use Basic view of Gmail, this behavior is not observed. So something related to javascript & Firefox/chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by using an external graphics adapter of Nvidia. The matrox g200 on-board display adapter seems to have issues with handling websites high content of javascripts and dynamic webpages.

One point I learned from this experience was, server motherboards would require Graphics adapters if they are to server as terminal servers in linux environment.